# How to translate the content of one second page?

Tags: angular

In my second page `about`, I will wish to translate the variable `Name` and get the value according the language. Here is my page html:

**about.component.html**

```
<p>about works!</p>

<div class="secondText">
  {{'Name' | translate }}
</div>
```

I have an error message -> `No pipe found with name 'translate'.`

I think the file `about.component.ts` is incomplete?

**about.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I tried to add this, but I always have the same problem.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'nl', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    console.log(42);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

My code is also [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g2njeg?file=src/app/about/about.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AboutComponent` to module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AboutComponent],
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mzwxtz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fabout%2Fabout.component.html)

Comment: For the page `Home`, how do you handle? I have the same problem...

Comment: @christine Same: `declarations: [AppComponent, AboutComponent, HomeComponent],` add  `HomeComponent` to declarations and import it: `import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';`

Comment: I had tried this, but my menu doesn't work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d1rwlt?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I see that once you are on `about` dropdown with `[en,nl,fr]` changes the text. I'm not sure about the menu. What is not working as expected?

Comment: It works !! Thank you a lot !! :-) Sorry for the disarrangement. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d1rwlt?file=src/app/app.component.html